# vue js get function not working but post is working

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to send a get request using axios from vue component.But I can't get any response from server.When i using *post* method working fine.

```
    created:function(){

        let Uri = process.env.VUE_APP_URL +'/apiF/customer/myOrders';
        this.axios.get(Uri).then((response) => {
            this.order_details = response.data
            
        }).catch(error => {
            this.errors_exist=true;
            if (error.response.status == 422){
            this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
            }
        })

    },
```

Comment: This code looks good to me. Is the server accepts POST requests on that endpoint? It looks like a server configuration issue.

Comment: @RobbeR Getting response while using post.

Comment: Cors.php -> public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    }

Comment: Debug it on server, log something on server when request are made, also log the response in front, or error if appears.

Comment: @Radeanu I think get method not hitting to server.Response is my template layout.But post can.